# is it possible to do webscraping on server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I made a simple web scraping program I tried this code locally on my machine it's working but when I run the same code on my server it's not working.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B085YG2X5K/ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_PRICEDP_5d1_w?pf_rd_m=A1K21FY43GMZF8&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=8WBM4CT83NFYZNGJW14A&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=42c4540d-2ecb-44d3-be4e-11aab9797e21&pf_rd_i=17024262031'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('span',{'id':'productTitle'}))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(soup.find_all('html'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 158: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Is there errors messages ?

Comment: Are you accessing your server on a SSH console?

Comment: What makes your own computer any different than "a server"? http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @MehdiFracso yes on putty

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course.
Servers aren't humans, they only need to get html code containing the data that you want to scrape.
They will run on a headless browser which means, a browser that is getting data without opening any window showing the rendered HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT, they will only get the data, grab the html tags matching your query and process your data as you instructed (printing it to console in your case).